# How can I find which version of PHP is used by Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm currently using two versions of PHP in my computer.
I can't remember which version of PHP is set for my Composer. So my question is how can I find which version of PHP is used by Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer uses /usr/bin/env to detect your php version. You can find it the correct version with `env php -v`.